# PyCharm/Django - cannot import module views.py (IDE is wrong)

Tags: django, intellij-idea, import, pycharm, django-urls

I'm having a weird problem with `import views` in `Django` project. I'm not sure whether it is a problem caused by `PyCharm` of `Django`. So `PyCharm` says that it can't `import` `views.py` file, but it works when I run the server.

Here is the picture:

[image]

Do you know where could be the problem?

**EDIT:** 
According to *Inlangers* answer, I've tried to change import to from `vlado_web.translations import views` which did not helped, moreover, it raises

`Exception Value:

No module named translations`

When I have `from translations import views` there, it works correctly but `PyCharm` says that it can't be resolved.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

PyCharm doesn't know where your source files are. Try this:

Right click on folder `vlado_web` (the folder that contains `manage.py`) within PyCharm. Go to `Mark Directory As` and choose `Sources Root`.

This will let PyCharm know that the `vlado_web` directory is the root folder for your source code, and will allow you to perform absolute imports from there, e.g.

```
from vlado_web.translations import views
```

Comment: This works. I didn't even know this option is available. Thank you kindly.

Answer (score 0):

Try `from vlado_web.translations import views`

Comment: It did not helped, I've added picture into my question (in EDIT section).